# Entity Framework Query execution timeout issue

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services, query-performance

Meet the following issue when working with EntityFramework v6.1.3

The query is:

```
var query = DataContext.ExternalPosts.Include(e => e.ExternalUser)
                       .Where(e => e.EventId == eventId)
                       .OrderByDescending(e => e.PublishedAt)
                       .Take(35);
```

When I do

```
query.ToList()
```

I get "The wait operation timed out" exception. But when I use query from

```
query.ToString()
```

and execute it directly on server (via Management Studio) it take about 150ms

I have updated CommandTimeout period to 180 and managed to get the result after 50sec via EntityFramework.
When I remove '.OrderByDescending' or '.Include' it works correct for me, I didn't measure the time but it works quite fast.

There is statistics: http://grab.by/KsQ2
I use AzureDb.

---

**UPDATE**:

New day, new situation: today it works quite normal with the same query and on the same set of data. Could this be Azure services issue?

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the query provided by ToString()?

Comment: Please provide some information about relation between `ExternalUser` and `ExternalPosts`. This is important as `Include` works using `JOIN` statements. Does it take 150ms in SSMS to first rows being displayed or is it for full result set? In your sample you don't use anything from `ExternalUser`. Do you really need to include that?

Comment: @KasparsOzols
Added statistics and query (hide full list cause I think it doesn't make sense).
and yes I need some info from ExternalPosts table after...

Comment: What tier of service are you using for your mobile service?  If you're running on the Free tier, you could definitely see it behaving more slowly than on Basic, so it's possible CPU throttling is the problem.